# dashcode and external rss feeds

Tags: rss, dashcode

I was wonder if anyone can help me with this. I've been looking everywhere for this information, but I want to make a web application using dascode rss. I  know that you can't link external sources. Does anyone know a way I can get around it. From what I understand a little php can get around this, but I'm unsure where to look.

Answer (score 0):

OK, first thing no PHP. Dashcode is limited to HTML, CSS and JavaScript. Although having said that there are a whole range of system calls that cna be made using the functionality provided by various parts of the x-cde system.

Second yes you can link to external sources such as other web sites, api on say Twitter, google etc. RSS feeds and so on, not sure where you got the idea to the contrary.

If you want to learn how to do a Dashcode RSS then open up Dashcode, start a new project, either web based or Dsashboard based and choose the RSS project. This will give you an out of the box template to add you own information and then see how it works. Then customise it.

In the above i am assuming Snow Leopard and the latest Dashcode/X-code but it will still gove you most of what you want on earlier version.